# Rails: Generate Json response based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, jbuilder

How to generate conditional based `JSON` response in `json.jbuilder` file.
For example:

```
json.posts @posts do |post|
    post.id post.id
    post.users.each do |user|
        if user.status == true
           json.name user.name
           json.age user.age
        else
           json.name user.supervisor_name
           json.age user.supervisor_age
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is, if `user.status == false` than it doesn't execute the else part.
Anyone can help?

I want response something like this:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      {
        "name": "Jhon",
        "age": "24"
      },
      {
        "name": "Wick",
        "age": "25"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      {
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": "32"
      },
      {
        "name": "Cruis",
        "age": "31"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
json.posts @posts do |post|
  json.id post.id
  json.users post.users do |user|
    if user.status == true
      json.name user.name
      json.age user.age
    else
      json.name user.supervisor_name
      json.age user.supervisor_age
    end
  end
end
```